# Plotly events not working with Spotfire Mods

Tags: javascript, dom-events, data-visualization, spotfire, plotly.js

While trying to create a funnel chart Mod in Spotfire using Plotly.js library, somehow plotly events are not working. Following the plotly documentation, we tried to add "plotly_selected", "plotly_hover" and "plotly_unhover" events which are triggered in the connecting area between the points rather than actual points.

We notice that the events are triggered when the mouse pointer is outside of the plotly chart elements. However, when we move the mouse pointer over the chart elements, the events are not triggered. We are unsure as to how to troubleshoot further. The code we have written works in a web browser, but not inside our application (Spotfire).

Below is Data preparation for chart:

```
 for (const colorLeaf of colorLeafNodes) {
        data.push({
            type: "funnel",
            name: colorLeaf.formattedPath(),
            y: colorLeaf.rows().map((y) => y.categorical("Category").formattedValue()),
            x: colorLeaf.rows().map((x) => x.continuous("Value Axis").value()),
            textposition: "inside",
            hoverinfo: "none",
            textinfo: "value+percent initial",
            textfont: {
                family: styling.general.font.fontFamily,
                size: styling.general.font.fontSize,
                color: styling.general.font.color.bgBlack
            },
            marker: {
                color: colorLeaf.rows().map((row) => row.color().hexCode)
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the Chart Div:

`var chartDiv = document.getElementById("mod-container");`

Plotly marking event

```
chartDiv
    .on("plotly_selected", function (eventData) {
                console.log("plotly_selected");
                console.log(eventData.points);
                let categories = [];
                let colorValues = [];

                if (eventData != null) {
                    if (eventData.points.length == 0) {
                        dataView.clearMarking();
                        return;
                    }
                    eventData.points.forEach((d) => {
                        console.log(d);
                        categories.push(d.y);
                        colorValues.push(d.data.name);
                    });

                    let rowsToMark = rows.filter(
                        (d) =>
                            categories.includes(d.categorical("Category").formattedValue()) &&
                            colorValues.includes(d.categorical("Color").formattedValue())
                    );
                    dataView.mark(rowsToMark);
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

After deeper troubleshooting, we found that CSS code was the troublemaker. After removing `.points g path { pointer-events: all; }` from CSS, plotly events were working smoothly with Mods.